# Cron not running CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, cron, shell

What am I doing wrong here? Trying to set a cron job to run a shell script but it won't work. I entered the below after doing `crontab -e`. It does show up when doing `contrab -l`.

```
0 2 * * * root /root/localbackup.sh
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it wont work"?

Comment: wont work = cron doesn't run  -- The script itself functions when hit manually

Comment: Have you looked in the cron log?  There should be an error message there that would say something like "root: command not found." which is explained by Iain's answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using the crontab format that's used for /etc/crontab. For the user crontabs you don't need to specify the user

```
 0 2 * * * /root/localbackup.sh
```

should run.

---

Answering the commants

The output from vi is normal, crontab will copy it to the correct location

- Check that [cron is running](https://serverfault.com/a/439817/9517)
- Check that there is a newline at the end of your command (crontab -e and press return at the end of the line)
- Check the root account's mail for any output that is mailed from cron.
- Capture the output of the command  `0 2 ... &>/tmp/mylog.log`

Comment: Still not running.  Revised to do `* * * * * /root/localbackup.sh` to test.  The path in VI editor states `"/tmp/crontab.QUz4Io" 2L, 62C`

Comment: @RonnieT: updated my answer.

Comment: Looks like I'm getting this error:  `/bin/sh: /root/localbackup.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: @RonnieT: That looks like you edited the script using windows (`^M` is a give away). On the CentOS machine run `dos2unix /root/localbackup.sh` this will convert it to unix format. Also ensure that the first line of your localbackup.sh is `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: Got it working.  Cron was not the issue it was the formatting of the shell file. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

run

```
service crond status
```

to see if cron is active.